# My java code has an obvious error. Why does it compile and run?

Tags: java, syntax

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println ("Hello ");
        http://www.google.com
        System.out.println ("World!");
    }
}
```

The above code is just compiling and executing fine. Why the compiler is not reporting any error?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `http:` is a [Label Statement](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/flow/labels.html). See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) also.

The `//www.google.com` portion is then interpreted as a `//` comment.

Answer (score 15):

Because `http:` it consider it as label and then rest part are under comment

Basic Usage of Label :

```
label1:
for(){
  label2:
  for(){
      if(condition1)
      break label1;//break outerloop

      if(condition2)
      break label2;//break innerloop
  }
}
```

- [**Sun Official Document Describing Label**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7)