# Website name in java program

Tags: java, url

```
public class Main  
{
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {
        http://google.com 
        System.out.println("Welcome");  
    }
}
```

Why is this code not getting a compilation error? and why did it get a compilation error if we write this url name after `System.out.println("Welcome");` ??

Comment: refer to some good java tutorial and learn syntax. What do u intend to do with the url?

Comment: See [My java code has an obvious error. Why does it compile and run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385432/my-java-code-has-an-obvious-error-why-does-it-compile-and-run) and [Why doesn't putting a random http link in code cause a compilation error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153943/why-doesnt-putting-a-random-http-link-in-code-cause-a-compilation-error)

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a label followed by a comment.

Comment: if we write only this http:\ then why not error ?

Comment: @user3329588 It *is* an error. Try compiling it.